# Unshrinkable windows/dialogs like Photo Booth in OS X - can I make them smaller?

Tags: macos, mac, window

On Mac OS X, some windows are a fixed size (eg. Photo Booth). Is there a way I can make them smaller to take up less space on a smaller screen?

Comment: You should switch your accepted response to Michael Neale -- that's  a slick way of doing it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually there is a solution:

Before launching an app, run from terminal: 
defaults write -g AppleDisplayScaleFactor 0.8
That will make all subsequent apps run at 80% size (you can set it back to 1 after it is launched).

To make this easy, create the following apple script (I turned it into an .app and gave it the icon for photobooth):

```
do shell script "defaults write -g AppleDisplayScaleFactor 0.8" 
tell application "Photo Booth" to launch 
do shell script "defaults write -g AppleDisplayScaleFactor 1"
```

Comment: That's pretty cool -- I never knew that!

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I believe the answer is **no**.</strike>

The only thing that may help is simply increasing your screen resolution.

Not a great answer, but I really don't think it's possible.

**Update**: See Michael Neale's response below for a really slick solution.

*But* there are some alternatives:

- [Funny Photographer](http://homepage.mac.com/spillnerclan/fabian/funnyphotographer/Funny%20Photographer.html)
- [WebCamTweaker](http://www.tweakersoft.com/webcamtweaker.html)

Comment: See below - there is a command line way - not for everyone, but works brilliantly. 

Those other apps look handy though.

Comment: Thanks for updating it. Actually, the solution below technically fools the app into thinking the screen is higher resolution, adding virtual pixels ;) Its a handy trick.

Answer (score 0):

On your keyboard simply hit the three keys <kbd>control</kbd> <kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> at the same time.

You can do this in the Photo Booth hidden menu at the top of the display as well under *View*.
I couldn't find an answer in Google but found this out in a roundabout manner.

Comment: The question was about making windows smaller.  Control-Command-F puts the app in full screen mode.